# How to show last selected Date in EditText when select Date again?

Tags: android, android-datepicker

[image]Here is the source for selecting the date. It is working properly but I want to change date when selecting date again.

```
private int year;
private int month;
private int day;
         signup_bday=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_signup_birthday);
         signup_bday.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             Calendar mcurrentDate=Calendar.getInstance();
                year=mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                month=mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                day=mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                DatePickerDialog mDatePicker=new       DatePickerDialog(CreateAccountActivity.this, new OnDateSetListener()
                {                  
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday) 
                    {
                     signup_bday.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month +  1).append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year).append(" "));
                    }
                },year, month, day);
                mDatePicker.setTitle("Please select date");                
                mDatePicker.show();
        }
    });
```

[image]

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-date-picker-example/

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "I want to change date"? Based on what? Are you attempting to refactor to pass a date (Calendar object) in?

Comment: nups just want to select date again and display the last date selected...

Comment: @Banku Let me guess when you open the date picker first time that time date is 1-Jan-2014. This get displayed in the Textview. Now when again you select different date in datepicker suppose 5-Jan-2014 then you want to update your textview's value to 5-Jan-2014, Am I correct ?

Comment: hmm same like tat... (here showing date in edittext...) @user3322955

Comment: @Banku your code says that it should work what you are asking. can you please upload more code ?

Comment: @appu bala i have followed your link but it is not what i am searching for?

Comment: @user3322955 i think that you got the edit...

Comment: @Banku sorry I havent worked on kindle fire HD before, I suggest you to post a new question so that you will get better answer from other sers as well.

Comment: @user3322955 Thnx for entire conversation ...
m on the way for solving this issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I solved your problem, Here is the code,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;
    private EditText signup_bday;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        signup_bday=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_signup_birthday);
        signup_bday.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Calendar mcurrentDate=Calendar.getInstance();
                year=mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                month=mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                day=mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                DatePickerDialog mDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new OnDateSetListener()
                {                  
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday) 
                    {
                        year = selectedyear; 
                        month = selectedmonth; 
                        day = selectedday;
                        signup_bday.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month +  1).append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year).append(" "));
                    }
                },year, month, day);
                mDatePicker.setTitle("Please select date");                
                mDatePicker.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You just need to add following lines in onDateSet() method,

```
year = selectedyear; 
month = selectedmonth; 
day = selectedday;
```

Comment: All is working fine but on kindle fire Hd datepicker dialog is not working properly...

Comment: @Banku, How does it shows datepicker on kindle fire HD ? Any image ?

Comment: It shows Alert with request Please select date
below text..
3 + + + sign 
and below 3 + sign 
3  - - - sign

Comment: @Banku , can you upload its image ?

Comment: hmm but it will take time...so adding web image...
it is not same as on Galaxy tab...

Answer (score 1):

I think your `onDateSet` method not getting called. Add `@override` annotation and try following code.

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

What I understood.. First time it displays current date. If user select 5,Jan 2014 then second time it'll display previously selected data(5, Jan 2014). If you are trying to achieve this then try something like this

```
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
try {
    cal.setTime(new Date(PREVIOUSLY_SELECTED_DATE));
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

}
```